# when integrating mathType top of tinymce I got error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, mathtype

I want to integrate mathType top of tinymce for creating formulas for both maths and chemistry.

I am using plugin like this:
external_plugins: { tiny_mce_wiris: 'https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/tiny_mce/plugin.js' },
toolbar: [ 'undo redo preview',
'tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditor',
'tiny_mce_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry ',
'blocks fontfamily fontsize ',
'bold italic underline strikethrough blockquote codesample codeformat subscript               superscript |
image table |
align lineheight |
checklist numlist bullist indent outdent |
emoticons charmap |
removeformat' ],

I am getting error like this

Uncaught TypeError:

tinymce.create is not a function
at plugin.js:1:1068526`your text`
at plugin.js:1:1076185
at plugin.js:1:1076189

want to create a functionality to generate formulas